# How to display the tasks of the current user only in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-enterprise

I have Tasks list in my SharePoint website and each task is assigned to a person based on a workflow. I want the tasks to be visible to the users only if they have been added to the workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the task list in displayed in a web part and you want to filter on assigned to:
Edit the page with the task list
Edit the web part and change the **Selected View** to **My Tasks**. This will filter the task list to only show tasks assigned to the current user.

If you need to filter on other columns you can create a custom view to display what you want. Then change the web part to use your view.

Comment: I am actually using content query web part for displaying the tasks in the front page of the site. How can I change the view of this content query web part to "My Tasks"?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use content query web part? I don't think it is possible using CQWB but a DVWB will work. see: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/finding-the-current-user-login-in-a-content-query-web-part

Comment: Couldn't you just use a filter, Assigned To Equals [Me] in the CQWP