# Task Management in My Sites

Tags: tasks, mysite

I want to filter the task in **My Task**. Below is the image:
[image]

Here the Tasks are coming from different lists like Task, Timesheet etc. But I want to show the data only from Tasks and not from Timesheet. I think all the tasks are coming whose **Content Type** is Tasks. Is it possible to filter in any ways so that only list of Tasks can be shown?

Comment: Hi your refer this below link: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61866/how-to-display-the-tasks-of-the-current-user-only-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: @Jayakumar : Thanks for your help.But its displaying current user's Tasks only. And I want to filter and want to show data only from one list.