# Display current Logged in user's Task and View all tasks when Admin login

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, workflow-tasks-list

I have a requirement where I want to display the tasks based on the current logged in user but when admin group logged in then he should be able to view all task.

While searching, I found [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61866/how-to-display-the-tasks-of-the-current-user-only-in-sharepoint-2010) question. It solved my first part.

But when admin group logged in then he should be able to view all task. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two views of same List and both on same Page.

1. First webpart with filter by [ME] which solved your first problem
2. Second web part without any filter which will show all the tasks

You can set permissions for the Web Part and apply respective group permissions to web part.

1 Webpart: Provide view access users and restrict same for Admin Group

2 Webpart: Provide view access to Admin Group and restrict users

This link may come in handy for you :[Manage and share Web Parts and Web Part Pages](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-and-share-Web-Parts-and-Web-Part-Pages-00ff95a0-62ba-42dc-91c3-bf0dba34e053?CorrelationId=fa688ffe-c128-44fc-b825-7d56f220c788&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010024106)